# How can I directly embed audio that I have uploaded to OneDrive into HTML using the <audio> element?

Tags: html, audio, onedrive

I would like to know how I can directly embed an audio file that I have uploaded to OneDrive in HTML using the `<audio>` element.

- I know there's always an `Embed` button in OneDrive, but I don't want that. That really only provides a big rectangle-shaped thing with a music icon and the filename, and when I click that, I'm still redirected to OneDrive. How can I really embed this using the HTML `<audio>` element?
- I actually already tried the `Copy Audio Location` menu item from Firefox's context menu. It gave me a link that worked in the Dreamweaver's Live Preview (in the split view), but it didn't work in any other browser, including Firefox and Chrome.
- I would like to use pure HTML to do this, i.e. no JavaScript.

Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can probably do it this way:

1. Get the direct link to the file:

   - [how to do it](https://bydik.com/onedrive-direct-link/):
   - Open OneDrive and Copy Embed Code
     [image]
   - Paste the Embed Code and Modify:
     Now paste the embed code you copied in a notepad or a text editor. This code looks like this one – `<iframe src="https://onedrive.live.com/embed?cid=FA476CAFF1A7E75C&resid=FA476CAFF1A7E75C%21122&authkey=AN_axXpcOy7Zfl8" width="98" height="120" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>`. You have to modify this code, remove everything except source URL of the file `https://onedrive.live.com/embed?cid=FA476CAFF1A7E75C&resid=FA476CAFF1A7E75C%21122&authkey=AN_axXpcOy7Zfl8` and then just replace embed with download to get direct/permanent link. After this modification, the link should look like this – `https://onedrive.live.com/download?cid=FA476CAFF1A7E75C&resid=FA476CAFF1A7E75C%21122&authkey=AN_axXpcOy7Zfl8`
   - That’s the OneDrive direct or native link
2. Use this link in the audio tag:

```
<audio src="https://onedrive.live.com/download?cid=FA476CAFF1A7E75C&resid=FA476CAFF1A7E75C%21122&authkey=AN_axXpcOy7Zfl8"></audio>
```

I mean provide into src the link you get from OneDrive.

Comment: @TechExpertWizard ok, I'm happy it works. Honestly I didn't try it myself 'cause I don't have any Windows machine and OneDrive (I use Linux).

Comment: Why can't you try it because you're on a Linux machine?

Comment: @TechExpertWizard I've got no OneDrive and I don't want to create one at the moment.

Comment: Oh, that's okay. Anyways, thanks for answering this question! I've been waiting for an answer for two months!

Comment: @TechExpertWizard do you really still need it? ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226348/discussion-between-tech-expert-wizard-and-victor-vosmottor).

Comment: Thanks, this helped me. Side note: I had to add `controls` to the `audio` tag.